# Not running at document_start

Tags: google-chrome-extension

My extension doesn't run at `document_start`. The manifest.json:

```json
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Lift Web Restrictions",
    "description": "Simple extension that removes most ads, web restrictions, adds mods to MooMoo.io / Krunker.io / and more!",
    "version": "0.0.5",
    "icons": {
        "16": "logo/sw16.png",
        "48": "logo/sw48.png",
        "128": "logo/sw128.png"
    },
    "permissions": [],
    "host_permissions": [
        "*://*/*"
    ],
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "service-worker.js"
    },
    "web_accessible_resources": [
        {
          "resources": ["modules/script.js"],
          "matches": ["*://*/*"]
        }
    ],     
    "content_scripts": [{
        "js": [
            "modules/transfer.js"
        ],
        "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
        "all_frames": true,
        "run-at": "document_start"
    }]
}
```

There's a `console.log` within `modules/transfer.js`, however the page's script tag beats it.

```js
Launching egAps
index.bf049c93.js?52f6f7bb66295262766e:2 Downloading d.js...

index.bf049c93.js?52f6f7bb66295262766e:2 Loading WASM c66eb3cbd8fdc1325900.wasm
^^^^ logged before script runs

index.bf049c93.js?52f6f7bb66295262766e:2 1 dependencies left
transfer.js:1 fireAt <--- where it runs
index.bf049c93.js?52f6f7bb66295262766e:2 0 dependencies left
index.bf049c93.js?52f6f7bb66295262766e:2 Running...
index.bf049c93.js?52f6f7bb66295262766e:2
```

Comment: Replace `run-at` with `run_at`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `run-at` with `run_at`

Thank you wOxxOm